# What is TortoiseMerge showing as "mine" and "theirs"?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I have two conflicting files, with contents `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6` (`1-6`) and `1\n2\n3\n4` (`1-4`), both based a file with contents `1\n2\n3\n4\n5` (`1-5`). However, this is what TortoiseMerge shows when resolving this conflict:

[image]

As you can see, the left and right panes do not show only `1-6` and `1-4`, but display `1-3,4-5,4-6` and `1-3,4-5,4`. There is an extra `4-5` in both files. What I can do in the third pane (apart from manually editing stuff) is, for each line or block, decide whether to keep the "mine" or use "theirs". But I find that resolving a conflict, I should need to work only the red blocks, deciding between the `4-6` from theirs or the `4` from mine. But either way, there's the extra `4-5`. (It seems this is the block from the common base which corresponds to the conflicted block in the two changed files. Is that correction? Why is it there? What should I do with that orange block? I can use either theirs or mine, no difference.

So what exactly is TortoiseMerge showing in the first two panes?

And in the third pane, how am I to decide for either the 1-4 or the 1-6 result without having to manually edit the result?

(This is how I created this conflict:

- Created new repo
- Checkout to WC1
- Checkout to WC2
- Create WC1\Test.txt with 1\n2\n3\n4\n5 as file contents
- Commit WC1\Test.txt
- Update WC2\Test.txt
- Add line 6 to WC1\Test.txt
- Commit WC1\Test.txt
- Remove line 5 from WC2\Test.txt
- Update WC2\Test.txt (--> Conflict)
- Edit conflict)

**Update:** I have just noticed that in the third pane, the orange lines are marked with a "--" (minus sign), indicating that these will not be saved in the merged file. And indeed they are not! I fail to understand why the first two panels show these lines with a "=" (equal sign), though.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to understand graphical 3-way merge tools but, sometimes, I understand the conflict almost instantly when I check the source file with the raw Subversion conflict markers. You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I think what is going on is this.

Let r1 be the common version, r2 the one with changes that I am updating, and WC my latest one with conflicting changes with respect to r2.

The first panel shows a *diff* between r2 (theirs) and r1.

The second panel shows a *diff* between WC (mine) and r1.

Note that each diff could be written more concisely (adding a single line on the left, removing a single line on the right). These two diffs are synchronized in a way that the deleted text (the orange blocks) are the same in the two diffs, hence the extra verbose output and the "=" signs. For some reason, the orange blocks are not marked as deletions in any other way.

The third panel shows a diff between (the merge of r2 and WC) and R1: this time, the deleted orange text is correctly marked as (to-be-)removed.

As I have assumed, I can resolve conflicts by simply going through all red blocks, deciding whether to use mine or theirs, and I do not have to touch any orange block at all.